# Seleccionar los valores "mayor a " de una consulta Datediff SQL

Tags: sql

la consulta consiste en calcular los días transcurridos desde la ultima modificación del registro, para ello utilizo este query y se muestra el resultado.

```
select Doc_nombre,DATEDIFF(day, Ultima_mod, GETDATE()) as Dias 
from ENT_DOCS 
order by Dias desc
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora bien lo que necesito solo es mostrar los resultados mayores a 600 días, intente con un where Dias >= pero como no es una columna no me lo permite, les agredeceria alguna idea para  complementar este query y llegar al resultado, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Ya intentaste con Top ##??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select Doc_nombre, DATEDIFF(day, Ultima_mod, GETDATE()) as Dias 
from ENT_DOCS
where DATEDIFF(day, Ultima_mod, GETDATE()) > 600 
order by Dias desc
```

Debes poner la **cláusula where** con el filtro deseado, pero sin usar el alias dado a la expresión en la **cláusula select**.

Puedes usar el alias en la **cláusula** **order by** y si usas **MySQL** también puedes usar los alias en la **cláusula** **having**, pero esto viola el estándar **SQL**. En la **cláusula where** no puedes usar alias, ya que los alias todavía no están creados en ese momento, las consultas **SQL** tiene un orden de ejecución, donde primero se ejecuta el **where**, y después el **select**, por lo que en el momento de la ejecución del **where** todavía no existen los alias del **select**.

Te recomiendo también que leas la respuesta de **Luis Cazares** que está muy interesante y explica cosas que yo no explico.

Comment: Muy buena tu explicación y muchas gracias me sirvió bastante.

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha servido, recuerda aceptarla y eventualmente darle al +1, es la forma "oficial" de decir Gracias! en Stack Overflow en español, además haces que el contenido perdure y pueda ayudar a otros usuarios.

Comment: Esta respuesta tiene varios errores que explico en la mía.

Comment: Hola @LuisCazares y disculpa que intervenga, pero no veo esos "varios errores" que comentas, no le explique el orden de las consultas con sus 6 pasos, pero le dije que primero se ejecuta el where y despues el select, pense que con eso bastaba. Por otra parte no sabia que usar funciones dentro de otras funciones puede traer problemas con los indices (lo aprendi ahora e investigare ese tema), pero es que tu haces lo mismo dentro del DateAdd, asi que esto no me queda muy claro. Saludos Luis y gracias

Comment: No se puede usar el alias en group by o having. Respecto a lo de que uso una función, si te fijas, la función del WHERE no se aplica a ninguna columna. La columna queda intacta del otro lado de la comparación. Tu respuesta funciona y responde a la pregunta, por eso no voté negativo. Sin embargo, no me parece que sea una respuesta óptima.

Comment: Si @LuisCazares, muy interesante, investigué un poco, y vi q en mysql si se puede usar el alias en el having, pero esto viola el estandar sql, enseguida arreglo eso en mi respuesta, respecto a lo otro de los indices podrias darme referencias para investigar mas, gracias

Comment: @Japv [Aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/post-migration-validation-and-optimization-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#inability-to-use-predicates-to-filter-data) hay un pequeño dato acerca del uso de índices. Estoy batallando para encontrar información completa en español, pero en general puedes obtener datos buscando acerca de predicados SARGable. Que se refieren a predicados que pueden buscar en índices.

Comment: Ok, @LuisCazares lo veo y lo estudio, gracias

Answer (score 2):

Como ya se mencionó en otra respuesta, los alias de las columnas no se han interpretado al momento de evaluar el `WHERE`. De forma muy básica, SQL Server realiza 6 pasos durante la interpretación/ejecución de una sentencia.

1. Obtener datos (From, Join)
2. Filtrar filas (Where)
3. Agrupar (Group by)
4. Filtrar grupos (Having)
5. Regresar expresiones (Select)
6. Ordenar & Paginar (Order by & Top / Offset)

Por esa razón, puedes usar el alias en el `ORDER BY`, pero no en el `WHERE`.

Sin embargo, otro problema es que no debes de utilizar funciones en funciones dentro de tus filtros, ya que eso evita el uso efectivo de índices y requiere que se lea toda la tabla para poder aplicar el filtro. Lo que necesitas es modificar la lógica y buscar todas las filas cuya fecha de modificación sea menor o igual a la fecha de hace 600 días.

```
SELECT  Doc_nombre,
        DATEDIFF(day, Ultima_mod, GETDATE()) AS Dias 
FROM ENT_DOCS 
WHERE Ultima_mod <= DATEADD( day, -600, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
ORDER BY Dias DESC;
```

Comment: Gracias Luis , te agradezco tu respuesta me queda mas claro el tema.